# How does drupal 7 know its version? which file does it check?

Tags: 7, version-control

Hi Im just curious to know where is the metadata of the version info, where does drupal have defined its version in the files...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`VERSION`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/VERSION/7) constant is defined on line 11 of `bootstrap.inc`:

```
/**
 * The current system version.
 */
define('VERSION', '7.41');
```